# WebBrowser Document Completed Event C#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

Below is the function I use as my browsers' `DocumentCompleted` event, and also the `navBtnClick()` method which is responsible for creating the web browser and navigating to a specific url.

```
public void WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {

                MessageBox.Show( ((WebBrowser)sender).Url.ToString() );

}



private void navBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            WebBrowser wbrowser = new WebBrowser();
            wbrowser.DocumentCompleted +=new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
            wbrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");

}
```

Now after this line `wbrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");` is executed, there is a message box correctly showing the url, and then after a while another message box shows with the same url. So, what happens is, whatever is on the `DocumentCompleted` event handler, gets executed twice. Can someone help me make it execute once only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I recall, DocumentCompleted will fire multiple times if the document being navigated to has iframes that embed other web pages.

If you only want to receive the event exactly once, just unsubscribe from the DocumentCompleted handler:

```
public void WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) 
{
   var webBrowser = sender as WebBrowser;
   webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
   MessageBox.Show(webBrowser.Url.ToString() );
}    

private void navBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var wbrowser = new WebBrowser();
     wbrowser.DocumentCompleted +=new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
     wbrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
}
```

---

Alternately, you can use System.IObservable and [ReactiveExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242978%28v=vs.103%29) to subscribe to exactly one event firing:

```
private void navBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var browser = new WebBrowser();
     var docCompleted = Observable.FromEventPattern<WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs>(browser, "DocumentCompleted")
     docCompleted
         .Take(1) // Take only one event firing
         .Subscribe(i => MessageBox.Show(browser.Url.ToString()));

     browser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, http://www.google.com redirects to http://www.google.ca.  If something similar happens for you, they you may be getting a document completed event for each of those two documents.  Try outputting/tracing `WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs.Url` to see what document was completed.